# How can I find the last "li" in a "ul" using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I want to check the `li` that is the last `li` in `ul`. How can I check that using jQuery?

```
<ul id="ulscroller">
    <li value="1" class="selected">1</li>
    <li value="2">2</li>
    <li value="3">3</li>
    <li value="4">4</li>
    <li value="5">5</li>
    <li value="6">6</li>
    <li value="7">7</li>
    <li value="8">8</li>
    <li value="9">9</li>
    <li value="10">10</li>
    <li value="11">11</li>
    <li value="12">12</li>
    <li value="13">13</li>
    <li value="14">14</li>
    <li value="15">15</li>
    <li value="16">16</li>
    <li value="17">17</li>
    <li value="18">18</li>
    <li value="19">19</li>
    <li value="20">20</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Check my answer. Seems like that is what you were asking.

Comment: `if ( $(this).is(':last') ) { ... }`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just use the [:last-child](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/) selector :

```
$('#ulscroller li:last-child')
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/f5v6R/

For example, if you want to know if it has the `selected` class you may do

```
if ($('#ulscroller li:last-child').hasClass('selected')) {
   // do something
}
```

Comment: yes but how can i check if i need to apply a logic ??
e.g.
if(IsLast_'li') then { ... } ??

Comment: @Arun what kind of logic ? What do you want to test ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `.last()` matcher

```
$('#ulscroller li').last()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('ul#ulscroller').children('li').last();
```

http://api.jquery.com/last/

You could also do it like so:

```
$('ul#ulscroller').children('li:last-child');
```

http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/

Here's an example to illustrate it: http://jsfiddle.net/TheNix/W92vF/

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$(function(){
    alert($('#ulscroller li:last-child').val());
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following

```
if($('#ulscroller li:last-child')[0] == liTocheck)
{
   alert("This is the last li");
}
```

Or

```
if($('#ulscroller li').last()[0] == liTocheck)
{
   alert("This is the last li");
}
```

Here `liTocheck` is the li that needs to be compared