# How to find the last ul in every li using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list

```
<ul class="mtree default">
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-224 cat-parent mtree-node mtree-open">
        <a href="#" style="cursor: pointer;">Lidingö</a>
        <ul class="children mtree-level-1">

            <li class="cat-item cat-item-444">
                <a href="#" style="cursor: pointer;">Direktåtkomst Förrådslänga</a>
                <ul class="children mtree-level-2">
                    <li class="cat-item cat-item-504">
                        <a>7 kvm (1199 kr/mån)</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="cat-item cat-item-314">
                <a href="#" style="cursor: pointer;">Hissplan</a>   
                <ul class="children mtree-level-2">
                    <li class="cat-item cat-item-674">
                        <a href="#">0,5 kvm (349 kr/mån)</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </li>

</ul>
```

Do you know how can I find the last ul of .cat-item-444 and cat-item-314 then select **7 kvm (1199 kr/mån)** and **0,5 kvm (349 kr/mån)** in one jquery code? The selected  tag should have .css('border', '1px solid red');

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527735/how-can-i-find-the-last-li-in-a-ul-using-jquery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find the last "li" in a "ul" using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527735/how-can-i-find-the-last-li-in-a-ul-using-jquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this you can use the `:last-child` selector to find the last `li` within each sub-level `ul`, like this:

```js
$('.cat-item > ul li ul li:last-child').addClass('foo');
```

```css
.foo {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="mtree default">
  <li class="cat-item cat-item-224 cat-parent mtree-node mtree-open">
    <a href="#" style="cursor: pointer;">Lidingö</a>
    <ul class="children mtree-level-1">
      <li class="cat-item cat-item-444">
        <a href="#" style="cursor: pointer;">Direktåtkomst Förrådslänga</a>
        <ul class="children mtree-level-2">
          <li class="cat-item cat-item-504">
            <a>7 kvm (1199 kr/mån)</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="cat-item cat-item-314">
        <a href="#" style="cursor: pointer;">Hissplan</a>
        <ul class="children mtree-level-2">
          <li class="cat-item cat-item-674">
            <a href="#">0,5 kvm (349 kr/mån)</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

</ul>
```

If you *only* want to get the `li` in the second level, and there are multiple lower levels then you'd need to add additional child selectors, something like `.cat-item > ul > li > ul > li:last-child`, but the above will work given the provided HTML.

Also note the use of `addClass()` over `css()`. This is preferred as you don't really want to put any styling rules directly in JS; they belong in CSS.

Comment: you are awesome

Answer (score 1):

what about a dynamic version :)

```js
$(".cat-item li:not(:has('ul')) a").addClass('foo');
```

```css
.foo {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="mtree default">
  <li class="cat-item cat-item-224 cat-parent mtree-node mtree-open">
    <a href="#" style="cursor: pointer;">Lidingö</a>
    <ul class="children mtree-level-1">
      <li class="cat-item cat-item-444">
        <a href="#" style="cursor: pointer;">Direktåtkomst Förrådslänga</a>
        <ul class="children mtree-level-2">
          <li class="cat-item cat-item-504">
            <a>7 kvm (1199 kr/mån)</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="cat-item cat-item-314">
        <a href="#" style="cursor: pointer;">Hissplan</a>
        <ul class="children mtree-level-2">
          <li class="cat-item cat-item-674">
            <a href="#">0,5 kvm (349 kr/mån)</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```js
$('.children li.cat-item').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).find('ul:last-child li a').text());

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="mtree default">
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-224 cat-parent mtree-node mtree-open">
        <a href="#" style="cursor: pointer;">Lidingö</a>
        <ul class="children mtree-level-1">

            <li class="cat-item cat-item-444">
                <a href="#" style="cursor: pointer;">Direktåtkomst Förrådslänga</a>
                <ul class="children mtree-level-2">
                    <li class="cat-item cat-item-504">
                        <a>7 kvm (1199 kr/mån)</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="cat-item cat-item-314">
                <a href="#" style="cursor: pointer;">Hissplan</a>   
                <ul class="children mtree-level-2">
                    <li class="cat-item cat-item-674">
                        <a href="#">0,5 kvm (349 kr/mån)</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.last()`:

```js
$('.cat-item-444 ul li').last().css('border','1px solid red');
$('.cat-item-314 ul li').last().css('border','1px solid red');
debugger
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="mtree default">
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-224 cat-parent mtree-node mtree-open">
        <a href="#" style="cursor: pointer;">Lidingö</a>
        <ul class="children mtree-level-1">

            <li class="cat-item cat-item-444">
                <a href="#" style="cursor: pointer;">Direktåtkomst Förrådslänga</a>
                <ul class="children mtree-level-2">
                    <li class="cat-item cat-item-504">
                        <a>7 kvm (1199 kr/mån)</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="cat-item cat-item-314">
                <a href="#" style="cursor: pointer;">Hissplan</a>   
                <ul class="children mtree-level-2">
                    <li class="cat-item cat-item-674">
                        <a href="#">0,5 kvm (349 kr/mån)</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </li>

</ul>
```