# How to create sub category on click ajax wordpress?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

Hi I'm want to create category wordpress on ajax. Example I have category A and category B.

Category A have 2 child and also category B have 2 child. First user must choose Category A or Category B, when selected Category A the option will be change to child category A.

After choose Child category A, user will be given option the grand child from category A. From last option will be redirect to list of post category user choose. And on the last page we output the user category choose. (Like Category A, Child Category A, Grand Child Category A)

Any suggestion ?

Solution:

Sorry everyone I think the title not correct. I found solution in here [Display Child Categories on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49644866/display-child-categories-on-click)

So I just using the jquery to hide and show the category on click. I hope this help everyone who have same problem.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want user to create category or just you want to show the category hierarchy they choose?

Comment: I want to show the category hierarchy they choose and create interaction ajax category @OutsourceWordPress

Comment: So, there will be any levels of parent-child hierarchy and a user can able to create a category at last level alone and not at intermediate level?

Comment: Also, why you need to redirect the user to the category page with posts since it will be just created?

Comment: hmm user/visitor cannot create category, I want to create step by step selection process and redirect visitor/user to category they choose. Example: They choose category soccer and next sub category europe and last choose category italy (soccer->europe->italy). User will redirect to list of soccer club in italy. Selection category process will be using ajax wordpress. Any Idea? @OutsourceWordPress

Comment: Why can't you have a single select box with all categories (with some indentation to show parent-child hierarchy) and redirect to selected category page?

Comment: Because this project need requirement using ajax selection process. I'm really confuse how to do it. @OutsourceWordPress

Comment: Okay update some code you have tried.

Comment: update for the solution @OutsourceWordPress

Comment: Glad to hear that, that's why I have asked why can't you achieve using single dropdown :)

Comment: Yes you're right, when I think about your suggestion, It can be possible using dropdown :D , Many thanks for your help :) @OutsourceWordPress

Comment: I got some question, I'm using wp list categories to display category but I'm want custom the output (Added some images and link only in the last child). Any suggestion ? @OutsourceWordPress

Comment: Instead you can use `get_categories()` - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/ and loop through each one and make necessary changes. You may also use 'jQuery' -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527735/how-can-i-find-the-last-li-in-a-ul-using-jquery and select last `li` to make required changes.

Comment: I created new question in here maybe you want to check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52689412/custom-output-wp-list-category , I have been try using this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36615440/get-all-categories-of-a-custom-post-type but I confuse to get the parent category and child category @OutsourceWordPress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two things basically: [wp_insert_term](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term) and some [AJAX functionality](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins).

> From last option will be redirect to list of post category user choose.

At this point, you can trigger your AJAX request. I suggest you attach the taxonomy term slugs as a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to the link:

`<a class="category_selection" href="#" data-taxonomy="tax_a" data-parentterm="parent_a" data-term="term_a">Cat A</a>`

You can bind a jQuery function to the click event:

```
$( document ).on( 'click', 'a.category_selection', function ( e ) {
    var data = {
                action: 'category_selection',
                term: $( this ).data( 'term' ),
                parent_term : $( this ).data( 'parentterm' ),
                taxonomy = $( this ).data( 'taxonomy' ),
                nonce: my_vars.ajax_nonce
            };
    $.ajax( {
                type: 'POST',
                url: my_vars.ajaxurl,
                data: data,
                async: true,
                success: function ( response ) {

                    // Parse response
                    var returndata = JSON.parse( response );

                    $( '.container' ).html( returndata );
                }
            } );
});
```

Now you need a PHP callback function that you can attach to the action `category_selection`. In this function, you will add the term to your category.

```
add_filter( 'wp_ajax_category_selection', 'add_term' );
add_filter( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_category_selection', 'add_term' );

function add_term() {
    check_ajax_referer( 'my_ajax', 'nonce' );
    $taxonomy = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'taxonomy', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
    // Sanitize the other input variables

    $newterm = wp_insert_term( $term, $taxonomy, array( 'parent' => $parent_term ) );

    if ( ! is_wp_error( $newterm ) ) :

        echo json_encode( array( 'Success' ) );

    endif;

    echo json_encode( array( 'Failure' ) );
    exit;
}
```

This should give you a rough overview how it could be handled. This is not meant for copy&paste, because some things are still missing, like creating an AJAX nonce or the `my_vars` javascript object that you need. You can find the necessary information in the Codex article I linked above.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response, I will try it @Michael

Comment: Hi Michael, I try the wp insert term and ajax but not success. Could you help me for some example ? @Michael

Comment: Sorry michael I don't have the code, I try tutorial create the ajax wordpress but cannot understand the system. I'm very newbie in ajax and this is my first time using ajax wordpress and wp insert term. Can you help me ? @Michael

Comment: My answer should do something like 90% of the work for you. If you don't want to do the rest yourself, you can always hire a coder. But stackoverflow is not there to give you a free solution that you can just copy&paste.

Comment: Oh okay I see. I will try again with my best and update the code in here. @Michael

Comment: Hi Michael, I finally found the solution. It's not ajax for the problem. I'm simply using the jquery on click for the categories @Michael

Comment: Hi Michael, I have another question about wp list category maybe you have some suggestion. Many thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52689412/custom-output-wp-list-category @Michael